# Debugging a Jenkins Plugin but using existing Jenkins

Tags: plugins, jenkins, hudson

I need to extend an existing plugin of our company for Jenkins.
The thing is, with the new and clean version that eclipse creates me (using maven with goal: hpi:run) I always get the problem that the plugin isn't embedded at all. Even though it is listed under "Manage Plugins" and the exact same version works fine if you deploy it as an hpi-file to a new jenkins installation.

So I found this: hpi:run -DhudsonHome=C:\Jenkins which supposedly should do the trick.
But it doesn't. It still uses a temporary folder next to src called "work".

When I took a look at the console output I recognized that the environmental system variable HUDSON_HOME wasn't set, so I did that and now it uses the existing Jenkins directory.

However, that is not an optimal solution because I'd need to use several Jenkins Servers on a Development-Machine. Is there any way I could get the -DhudsonHome Parameter to work?

Thanks.
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In eclipse, under the run configuration you have made, look at the JRE tab. In the box for VM arguments you can add -DJENKINS_HOME=.

Comment: Perfect, this did the trick. Thanks a lot. This way it is possible to have multiple jenkins in different workspaces, thanks a lot.